# Replace Canonical’s Firefox with Mozilla’s one on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: firefox, 20.04, search, canonical

I am not comfortable with the idea how Canonical implements it’s name in all DuckDuckGo search queries in Ubuntu. Maybe it’s not a huge privacy issue but I just don’t like such practices happening without my permission or even giving the choice to opt out. I realize that the company behind Ubuntu has to make money somehow and that’s OK.

To the point: I would like to remove ‘t=canonical’ string in DDG url bar search. However, it seems this is not possible anymore via editing the ddg xml files as described in earlier AskUbuntu questions. Removing the DDG search engine and re-adding it does not solve the issue as well.

That being said I guess my question really is: can I purge Canonical’s Firefox entirely and re-installing a pristine Mozilla’s browser while keeping ALL my user settings (including add-ons and about:config tweaks). I don’t believe in Firefox cloud profiles and I don’t want to create one for this purpose.

So after uninstalling Ubuntu’s stock Firefox which exact folders should I delete and which must I keep before installing Firefox from source in order to preserve my custom settings?

edit: The solutions provided here seem to not work on newer Firefox versions as mentioned above.
[How to remove `t=canonical` from Firefox browser searches made on DuckDuckGo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/577286/how-to-remove-t-canonical-from-firefox-browser-searches-made-on-duckduckgo)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove \`t=canonical\` from Firefox browser searches made on DuckDuckGo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/577286/how-to-remove-t-canonical-from-firefox-browser-searches-made-on-duckduckgo)  FYI your browser is still going to advertise "Ubuntu" in user-agent